# Select google spreadsheets to send specific tabs via email

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I found this code to send by email all tabs of a Google Spreadsheet as a PDF file (one merged file).

```
function sendReport() {
var message = {
to: "contact@sexample.com",
subject: "Sales Reports",
body: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s",
name: "Sales",
attachments:[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("sales_report_2021")]
}
MailApp.sendEmail(message);
```

So, I'd like to merge into the final document only the tabs that "A1" cell is equal "1" and send them by email as attachment.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create a PDF data with only the tabs of when the cell "A1" is `1`.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function sendReport() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ranges = ss.createTextFinder("1").matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
  var showSheets = ranges.reduce((ar, e) => {
    if (e.getA1Notation() == "A1") ar.push(e.getSheet().getSheetName());
    return ar;
  }, []);
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(s => {
    if (!showSheets.includes(s.getSheetName())) s.hideSheet();
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var pdf = ss.getBlob().setName("sales_report_2021");

  var message = {
    to: "contact@sexample.com",
    subject: "Sales Reports",
    body: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s",
    name: "Sales",
    attachments: [pdf]
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);

  sheets.forEach(s => s.showSheet());
}
```

- In this modification, the cells which have `1` are retrieved from all sheets using TextFinder. And, the sheets that the cell "A1" has `1` are retrieved. And, the sheets that the cell "A1" has no value of `1` are hidden. And then, the Spreadsheet is converted to a PDF data, and used with `MailApp.sendEmail`. At last, all sheets are shown. By this flow, your goal is achieved.

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [hideSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideSheet())
- [showSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showsheet)